# NGXS storage-plugin change between local & session storage

Tags: angular, local-storage, session-storage, ngxs

I'm using NGXS with the `@ngxs/storage-plugin`. When I import the plugin inside my module I can config the plugin to use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` via the `storage` option.

My App should use `localStorage` when the user checks the "remember me" option when logging in and use `sessionStorage` when he wont use the "remember me" option.

Any ideas how I can implement this with the `@ngxs/storage-plugin`?

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        NgxsModule.forRoot(STATES_MODULES, OPTIONS_CONFIG),
        NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot({storage: '????'}),
        NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule.forRoot(DEVTOOLS_REDUX_CONFIG),
        NgxsLoggerPluginModule.forRoot(LOGGER_CONFIG)
    ],
    exports: [NgxsModule]
})
export class NgxsStoreModule {}
```

Comment: You can't change the plugin options at runtime. You'll have to write your own plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a custom storage engine:
https://www.ngxs.io/plugins/storage#custom-storage-engine

If you can control your storage engine then that might work. Not sure if you can use angular's DI to inject the store/something else to figure out if the user is trying to set 'rememberMe' or not.

```
export class MyStorageEngine implements StorageEngine {
  ....

  setItem(key: string, val: any): void {
    if (rememberMe) {
      // set with localStorage
    } else {
      // set with sessionStorage
    }
  }
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good tip from @Richard.Davenport. Thanks. Here is implementation:

```
export class StorageEngineService implements StorageEngine {
 sessionStorageStates = ['exampleStorageSessionStateName'];
 readonly length: number = sessionStorage.length + localStorage.length;

 clear(): void {
   sessionStorage.clear();
   localStorage.clear();
 }

 getItem(key: string): any {
   let val: any;
   if (this.sessionStorageStates.includes(key)) {
     val = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
   } else {
     val = localStorage.getItem(key);
   }
   return val;
 }

 removeItem(key: string): void {
   if (this.sessionStorageStates.includes(key)) {
     sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
   } else {
     localStorage.removeItem(key);
   }
 }

 setItem(key: string, val: any): void {
   if (this.sessionStorageStates.includes(key)) {
     sessionStorage.setItem(key, val);
   } else {
     localStorage.setItem(key, val);
   }
 }
```

In App.Module:

```
...
    {
      provide: STORAGE_ENGINE,
      useClass: StorageEngineService,
    },
...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).